# Ruby, looping through a string deleting groups of characters until a desired output is achieved

Tags: ruby

I have a coding problem I solved and want to refactor. I know there has to be a cleaner way of doing what I did.

The goal is to write a method that takes a string of `"!"` and `"?"` and reduces the string by eliminating all odd groupings of each symbol.

Example - a string `"????!!!"` would have an odd grouping of `"!!!"` because there are three in a row. These would be deleted from the string.

If there is only one `"!"` or `"?"` its left because it is not in a group.

Ex -

```
remove("!????!!!?") answer == "!"    
# => ("!????!!!?" --> "!?????" --> "!")
```

In the first string, the only odd grouping is `"!!!"`, once removed, it leaves a new string with an odd grouping `"?????"`. You remove the next odd grouping so you're left with `"!"`. This fits the desired output.

Another example

```
remove("!???!!") == ""
# => ("!???!!" --> "!!!" --> "")
```

Current code:

```
def remove(s)
  arr = [s]
  i = 0

  until i == arr[0].length
    s = s.chars.chunk{|c|c}.map{ |n,a| a.join }.select{|x| x if x.length.even? || x.length <= 1}.join
    arr << s
    i += 1
  end 

  return arr[-1]
end
```

My code solves this problem and all test cases. I have a suspicion that my until loop can be removed/refactored so that I could solve this problem in one line and have spent hours trying to figure it out with no luck.

Comment: You had enough attention to your question, appreciate the given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose

```
str = "???!!!???!"
```

If we first remove the two groups `"???"` we are left with `"!!!!"`, which cannot be reduced further.

If we first remove the group `"!!!"` we are left with `"??????!"`, which cannot be reduced further.

If we are permitted to remove all odd groups of either character without reference to the effect that either has on the other, we obtain `!`, which cannot be reduced further.

It's not clear what rule is to be used. Here are three possibilities and code to implement each.

I will use the following two regular expressions, and in the first two cases a helper method.

```
Rq = /
     (?<!\?)  # do not match a question mark, negative lookbehind
     \?       # match a question mark
     (\?{2})+ # match two question marks one or more times
     (?!\?)   # do not match a question mark, negative lookahead
     /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

which is commonly written `/(?<!\?)\?(\?{2})+(?!\?)/`.

Similarly,

```
Rx = /(?<!!)!(!{2})+(?!!)/

def sequential(str, first_regex, second_regex)
  s = str.dup
  loop do
    size = s.size
    s = s.gsub(first_regex,'').gsub(second_regex,'')
    return s if s.size == size
  end
end
```

I apply each of the three methods below to two example strings:

```
str1 = "???!!!???!"
str2 = 50.times.map { ['?', '!'].sample }.join
  #=> "?!!!?!!!?!??????!!!?!!??!!???!?!????!?!!!?!?!???!?"
```

**Replace all odd groups of `"?"` then odd groups of `"!"` then repeat until no further removals are possible**

```
def question_before_exclamation(str)
  sequential(str, Rq, Rx)
end

question_before_exclamation str1 #=> "!!!!"
question_before_exclamation str2 #=> "??!??!?!!?!?!!?"
```

**Replace all odd groups of `"!"` then odd groups of `"?"` then repeat until no further removals are possible**

```
def exclamation_before_question(str)
  sequential(str, Rx, Rq)
end

exclamation_before_question str1 #=> "??????!"
exclamation_before_question str2 #=> "??!????!!?!?!!?!?!!?"
```

**Replace all odd groups of both `"?"` and `"!"` then repeat until no further removals are possible**

```
Rqx = /#{Rq}|#{Rx}/
  #=> /(?-mix:(?<!\?)\?(\?{2})+(?!\?))|(?-mix:(?<!!)!(!{2})+(?!!))/

def question_and_explanation(str)
  s = str.dup
  loop do
    size = s.size
    s = s.gsub(Rqx,'')
    return s if s.size == size
  end
end

question_and_explanation str1 #=> "!"
question_and_explanation str2 #=> "??!?!!?!?!!?!?!!?"
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong (this is ruby, after all) but I don't think you'll find a one-liner for this because ruby's utility functions generally aren't recursive. But you can use regex to simplify your logic, at the very least:

```
def remove(s)
  while s =~ /(?<!\!)\!([\!]{2})+(?!\!)/ || s =~ /(?<!\?)\?([\?]{2})+(?!\?)/
    s.gsub! /(?<!\!)\!([\!]{2})+(?!\!)/, ""  # remove odd !
    s.gsub! /(?<!\?)\?([\?]{2})+(?!\?)/, ""  # remove odd ?
  end
  return s
end
```

To make the regex less mind-boggling, it helps to look at them with 'a' instead of '?' and '!':

```
/(?<!a)a([a]{2})+(?!a)/ #regex for 'a'

(?<!a) #negative lookbehind: the match cannot start with an 'a'

a([a]{2})+ #the match should be an 'a' followed by 1 or more pairs

(?!a) #negative lookahead: the match cannot end with an 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact Ruby syntax for this, but you could simplify your solution by using regular expressions:

1. Gather all matches of consecutive characters

   - if all matches are of even length or 1 exit
2. Test if matches are an odd length

   - if an odd length, replace with the empty string
   - else do nothing
3. Goto step 1

A solution in Perl would be:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my $string = '!????!!!?';
sub reduce {
  my ($s) = @_;
  while ( my @matches = $s =~ m/((.)\2+)/g ) {
    last if ! grep { length($_) > 1 && length($_) % 2 == 1 } @matches;
    foreach my $match ( @matches ) {
      $s =~ s/\Q$match// if length($match) > 1 && length($match) % 2 == 1;
    }
  }

  return $s;
}

say reduce($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple enough with a regular expression replacement

```
def remove(string)
  begin
    original = string
    string.gsub!(/(\!{3,})|(\?{3,})/) { |s| s.length.even? ? s : '' } 
  end until original == string
  string
end

puts remove("!????!!!?").inspect # answer == "!"
puts remove("!???!!").inspect    # answer == ""
puts remove("!????!!").inspect   # answer == "!????!!"
```